# Mysql stored procedure parallel processing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

can we call stored procedures in parallel way to increase execution speed. for eg: I have three stored procedures to extract data from three master tables and load/insert it into the single source table.Currently i am having three procedures :

```
CALL sp_1(); 
CALL sp_2(); 
CALL sp_3();
```

and running it in a sequential way to insert the records which takes more time. Is there any way to run all these procedures in parallel way to improve execution time and speed up the process..Kindly help me with a possible work around for this.

Comment: Can you not just call them separately? From different client processes?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JustinMcAleer

Comment: But my question is how call them different clients@JustinMcAleer

Comment: How to open a connection in mysql within a same database and call the three procedures inside three separate connections ??? please help me out @JustinMcAleer I am lookin into this for past two days but cant zero in a solution.PLease suggest me some ideas

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql currently?

Comment: The process is pure backend process. I am connecting to mysql server from my gui sqlyog or command line..

Comment: Data from GPS devices fall into master tables and I am extracting(select) the data based on some conditions and inserting it into another table.So its a pure backend process

Comment: So, for example with sqlyog, do File>New Connection Using Current Settings. Then you have two separate connections you can use independently.

Comment: Before you go to the trouble of coordinating parallel processes, I recommend you identify why the current process is slow. Is it due to poor performance of SQL queries because they are written in a way that prevents efficient use of indexes. Or worse, because its processing a set row-by-agonizing-row rather than as a set. (Running separate INSERT statement for each row is going to be agonizingly slow.) If the bottleneck is storage I/O, then parallel-izing the process probably won't speed it up.

Comment: how can i run the stored procedures in parallel way?? if i open two connections explicitly from sqlyog??

Comment: @spencer7593 I have fine tuned the current process. It is slow because i am creating a cursor and looping the values one by one and inserting it into source table.After inserting the records i have to update flag status in master table,So if i replace looping with bulk insert it will be difficult to track the failure cases in insert.

Comment: Well, yes. Open a connection, run sp_1. While that runs, open another connection, run sp_2. etc.

Comment: @JustinMcAleer can this be done inside stored procedure.For eg: Can i create connections inside a stored procedure and call these stored procedures inside these connections??

Comment: What is wrapper procedure in mysql or multithreading in mysql is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** can we call stored procedures in parallel way to increase execution speed.

**A:** The short answer is no. There's no built-in mechanism (in MySQL) that will make a stored procedure run "in parallel". To achieve parallel processing, the application would need to be designed to do that, making use of multiple connections to MySQL, splitting the processing into chunks that can be run in parallel, and coordinating those processes.

As far as "increase execution speed", you'd really need to first identify what is causing the slowness.

If the issue is storage I/O, then parallel-izing the process is likely not going to increase execution speed.

If the procedure is using a cursor, to process a set row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR), and running a separate INSERT statement for each row, that process is bound to be agonizingly slow. In this case, you'd really need to explore how to get the rows processed in reasonably sized sets.

It's also possible that the procedure is executing SQL statements that are written in a way that prevents MySQL from making efficient use of available indexes. Or, appropriate indexes may not be available.

Before launching down the path of parallel-izing a process, it's important to understand what the actual bottleneck is. Running a process "in parallel" won't necessarily increase execution speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation @spencer7593

Answer (score 0):

Create a number of Events to submit the jobs at the same time.

The only problem is you can't create events from a stored procedure.